# how to solve "to create a new mock, the existing mock registration must be deregistered"

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I am getting the Following Exception when trying to mock a static method:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  For
> de.msggillardon.system.UserContext, static mocking is already
> registered in the current thread To create a new mock, the existing
> static mock registration must be deregistered

For the following Code:

```
 @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
// @PrepareForTest(UserContext.class)
public class KonfigurationCopyServiceTest {

  public static final String CONFIGURATION_NAME = "Standard-Konfiguration";

  @Mock
  public TriggeringKonfigurationService triggeringKonfigurationService;
  @Mock
  public ReportKonfigService reportConfigurationService;
  @Mock
  public BuchungsschemaService buchungsschemaService;

  public KonfigurationCopyService copyService;

  @BeforeEach
  public void init() {
    Mockito.mockStatic(UserContext.class);
    Mockito.when(UserContext.getUsername()).thenReturn("superuser");

    copyService = new KonfigurationCopyService(triggeringKonfigurationService,
        reportConfigurationService, buchungsschemaService);
  }
```

Can anyone help please?

Thank you!

Edit: UserContext.java

```
package de.msggillardon.system;

/**
 * This class contains the username and IP-address of the logged in user. It is initialized for each
 * session.
 *
 * @author wildp
 */
public class UserContext {

  private static final ThreadLocal<UserContext> userContext = new ThreadLocal<>();

  private final String username;

  private final String clientIPAddress;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param username        Username of the user who is logged in
   * @param clientIPAddress IP Address of the user who is logged in
   */
  public UserContext(String username, String clientIPAddress) {
    this.username = username;
    this.clientIPAddress = clientIPAddress;
  }

  /**
   * Initializes the threadLocal
   *
   * @param userContext
   */
  public static void initialize(UserContext userContext) {
    UserContext.userContext.set(userContext);
  }

  /**
   * Removes the current thread's value for this thread-local variable.
   */
  public static void remove() {
    userContext.remove();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the username of the current thread.
   *
   * @return
   */
  public static String getUsername() {
    return userContext.get().username;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the IP address of the client of the current thread.
   *
   * @return
   */
  public static String getClientIPAddress() {
    return userContext.get().clientIPAddress;
  }

  public static UserContext getThreadLocalUserContext(){
    return userContext.get();
  }
}
```

NEW EDIT:
I once again edited my Code so you can see now, that I am using @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.lass) to Mock.

Also I found the following tip online: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.3/org/mockito/MockedStatic.html
So it seems like I have to do a MockedStatic.close(); maybe as a @AfterEach
But when I am trying it gives me the Exception

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method close() from the type ScopedMock

Still not working :(

Comment: Could you please add the UserContext class here?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. How can it be PowerMockito if I don't have a powermockito import or dependencies in the pom? Also I added the UserContext class

Comment: You are correct, I apologize. Mockito has added the static mocking feature as of version 3.4. I wasnt aware of that. But honestly, I dont think that was a good idea. **static** mocking should be your very last resort, you only do it if there is no other way to get to a meaningful test.

Comment: I just edited my Question, maybe that helps. I found the MockedStatic.close() method online (see Edited Question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I use Junit 5 I couldn't use the @Before Annotation so I replaced the @BeforeEach with @BeforeAll.
So I did it as following:

1. Step: Import

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS;
```

2. Step: Add The @TestInstance(PER_CLASS) Annotation (before your class)
3. Step: @BeforeAll instead of @BeforeEach

That solved my Problem.

Comment: Didnt know that Before is now BeforeAll. So I learned something myself, too . Good self-answer!

Comment: I feel like the lifecycle annotation isn't really needed. That would indicate you have some other shared-state issue across tests

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

```
  private MockedStatic<UserContext> mockStatic;

  @BeforeEach
  public void beforeEach() {
    mockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(UserContext.class);
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void afterEach() {
    mockStatic.close();
  }
```

Comment: +1 This is the appropriate answer; in case you need static mock inside only one test method call close() directly to avoid any other issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
@BeforeEach
```

to  `@Before`

That message tells you: you did setup that static mocking before. Because `@BeforeEach` will do exactly that: run that `init()` method before **each** of your test methods. Change your setup to run the method **once**, not **n times**.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there is another class which also call `mockStatic()` on the same class but doesn't call `close()`, which affects my current test class.

```
public class Test2 {
  @AfterEach
  public void afterEach() {
    mockStatic.close();
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mock that object?

```
  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConfigurationCopyServiceTest {
    private UserContext userContext = new UserContext("superUser", "127.0.0.1");
    private ConfigurationCopyService configurationCopyService;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        UserContext.initialize(userContext);
        configurationCopyService = new ConfigurationCopyService(triggeringKonfigurationService,
    reportConfigurationService, buchungsschemaService);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void user_name_should_be_same_as_context() {
        assertEquals(UserContext.getUsername(), configurationCopyService.myMethod());
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue because my class was annotated with

`@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`

**and**

`@SpringBootTest`

**Removing @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) solved the problem for me**

Comment: This would effectively disable any `@Mock` annotations, if they are used, and instead would rely on calling `initMocks` for those or replacing all with static mock calls

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans "Spring Boot includes a @MockBean annotation that can be used to define a Mockito mock" and "If your test uses one of Spring Boot’s test annotations (such as @SpringBootTest), this feature is automatically enabled."